# How to pass arguments to add_action()

Tags: hooks, actions

I declared an action for a single event in Wordpress which accepts an array as an argument:

```
$asins = array(); //I had to declare this since I'm getting a notice of undefined variable if I don't

add_action('z_purge_products_cache', array($this, 'purge_products_cache', $asins));
```

I also tried this one, but it doesn't perform the action either:

```
add_action('z_purge_products_cache', array($this, 'purge_products_cache'));
```

Then I schedule it:

```
wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 20, 'z_purge_products_cache', $asins_r);
```

Then here's the function that will be called once wp cron executes the action:

```
public function purge_products_cache($asins){
  //send email here
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter needs to be passed to the callback function in the [wp_schedule_single_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event) function, not the [add_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) function.

Try this:

```
add_action('z_purge_products_cache', array($this, 'purge_products_cache'));
```

Then schedule the event, putting the parameter in an array:

```
wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 20, 'z_purge_products_cache', array($asins_r));
```

Your `purge_products_cache` function will be called with parameter `$asins_r`.

Comment: The method that I'm trying to call is inside the class so I had to use the `$this` keyword. This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: wp_schedule_single_event needs to send the parameters in an array.  See [this example from the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event#Schedule_an_event_one_hour_from_now_with_arguments).  I've updated the answer, including a new add_action line.

Answer (score -4):

Passing Argument in add_action() just see  the following example  ,

```
  function email_friends( $post_ID )  
{
   $friends = 'bob@example.org, susie@example.org';
   wp_mail( $friends, "sally's blog updated", 'I just put something on my blog: http://blog.example.com' );

   return $post_ID;
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'email_friends' );
```

[Brief explanation about add_action() is here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Parameters)

Comment: You didn’t pass any argument to `add_action()` in your example.